# Error Eclipse Project library

Tags: android, eclipse

see my screen :

http://it.tinypic.com/r/xpa240/8

I can not fix these errors. It seems that it does not generate the class R.

I've tried everything!
Clean the project,
Install all tools

help me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

1 - File->Import (android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7). Choose "appcompat"

2 - Project-> properties->Android. In the section library "Add" and choose "appCompat"

3 - That is all!

Answer (score 0):

The R class is generated automatically by the Android Eclipse plugin when it can. Here, I can see a red cross on your "res" folder so I think you should have some errors on your resources naming or type or something else : just look what your IDE is telling you !

Fix all errors that are not "R class missing" related and this class will be generated.

Comment: Ok looking at it gives me error in the layout.

in particular:
"error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found That matches the given name
  'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. "

Comment: So, here you have your error :) Fix it (remove the theme for testing purpose and try to add correct dependencies if you want to use Theme.AppCompat.Light)